# Haskell Pattern Matching (beginner)

Tags: haskell, matching, fold

I have to implement a small programm in Haskell that increments/decrements a result by what in the console line is. For example if we have -a in the console the results must be 0, if -b the result must be incremented with 6 and so on. I have to do this with pattern matching.

I haven't used Haskell until now and I find it pretty hard to understand. I have this to start with:

```
import System.Environment
main = getArgs >>= print . (foldr apply 0) . reverse
apply :: String -> Integer -> Integer
```

I don't understand what in the main is. What does it make and the reverse from end, what does it do? As I've read on the internet the getArgs function gives me the values from the console line. But how can I use them? Are there are equivalent functions like for/while in Haskell?

Also, if you have some examples or maybe could help me, I will be very thankful.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, do you know about hoogle? https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=reverse

Comment: But, yeah if you are really starting with Haskell, I'd recommend looking at simpler stuff than this `main`. http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters is great to understand the basics.

Comment: Is this an exercise from a course? The code they've given you is really not a good teaching example

Answer (score 5):

This is not beginner-friendly code. Several shortcuts are taken there to keep the code very compact (and in pointfree form). The code

```
main = getArgs >>= print . (foldr apply 0) . reverse
```

can be expanded as follows

```
main = do
  args <- getArgs
  let reversedArgs = reverse args
      result = foldr apply 0 reversedArgs
  print result
```

The result of this can be seen as follows. If the command line arguments are, say, `args = ["A","B","C"]`, then we get `reversedArgs = ["C","B","A"]` and finally

```
result = apply "C" (apply "B" (apply "A" 0))
```

since `foldr` applies the function `apply` in such way.

Honestly, I'm unsure about why the code uses `reverse` and `foldr` for your task. I would have considered `foldl` (or, to improve performance, `foldl'`) instead.

Comment: Using `foldl (flip apply) 0` without reversing does work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I expect the exercise is not to touch the given code, but to expand on it to perform your function. It defines a complicated-looking `main` function and declares the type of a more straight forward `apply`, which is called but not defined.

```
import System.Environment   -- contains the function getArgs
-- main gets arguments, does something to them using apply, and prints
main = getArgs >>= print . (foldr apply 0) . reverse
-- apply must have this type, but what it does must be elsewhere
apply :: String -> Integer -> Integer
```

If we concentrate on `apply`, we see that it receives a string and an integer, and returns an integer. This is the function we have to write, and it can't decide control flow, so we can just get to it while hoping the argument handling works out.

If we do want to figure out what `main` is up to, we can make a few observations. The only integer in `main` is `0`, so the first call must get that as its second argument; later ones will be chained with whatever is returned, as that's how `foldr` operates. `r` stands for from the right, but the arguments are `reverse`d, so this still processes arguments from the left.

So I could go ahead and just write a few `apply` bindings to make the program compile:

```
apply "succ"   n = succ n
apply "double" n = n + n
apply "div3"   n = n `div` 3
```

This added a few usable operations. It doesn't handle all possible strings.

```
$ runhaskell pmb.hs succ succ double double succ div3
3
$ runhaskell pmb.hs hello?
pmb.hs: pmb.hs:(5,1)-(7,26): Non-exhaustive patterns in function apply
```

The exercise should be about how you handle the choice of operation based on the string argument. There are several options, including distinct [patterns](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-580003.17) as above, pattern guards, [`case`](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-460003.13) and [`if`](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-320003.6) expressions.

It can be useful to examine the used functions to see how they might fit together. Here's a look at a few of the used functions in `ghci`:

```
Prelude> import System.Environment
Prelude System.Environment> :t getArgs
getArgs :: IO [String]
Prelude System.Environment> :t (>>=)
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
Prelude System.Environment> :t print
print :: Show a => a -> IO ()
Prelude System.Environment> :t (.)
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
Prelude System.Environment> :t foldr
foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
Prelude System.Environment> :t reverse
reverse :: [a] -> [a]
```

This shows that all the strings come out of [`getArgs`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-11.16/base-4.10.1.0/System-Environment.html#v:getArgs), it and [`print`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-11.16/base-4.10.1.0/Prelude.html#v:print) operate in the `IO` monad, which must be the `m` in `>>=`, and `.` transfers results from the right function into arguments for the left function. The type signature alone doesn't tell us what order [`foldr`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldr) handles things, though, or what [`reverse`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:reverse) does (though it can't create new values, only reorder including repetition).

As a last exercise, I'll rewrite the `main` function in a form that doesn't switch directions as many times:

```
main = print . foldl (flip apply) 0 =<< getArgs
```

This reads from right to left in a data flow sense and handles arguments from left to right because `foldl` performs left-associative folding. `flip` is just there to match the argument order for `apply`.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comment, hoogle is a great tool.
To find out what exactly you get from `getArgs` you can search for it on hoogle:

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/System-Environment.html#v:getArgs
As you can see, it's of type `IO [String]`.
Since I don't know how familiar you are with the IO abstractions yet, we'll just say that the right part of `>>=` gets those as argument.

The arguments for a call like `./a.out -a -b --asdf Hi` will then be a list of strings:

`["-a", "-b", "--asdf", "Hi"]`.

The fold + reverse in the main will then do some magic, and your `apply` function will be called with each string in the list and the previous return value (`0` for the first invocation).

In Haskell, `String` is the same as `[Char]` with a bit of compiler sugar, so you can match on strings like you would on regular lists in your definition of `apply`.

Comment: Yet another option: `:t` in GHCI.